# Run drush cron for a single module

Tags: drush, cron

Is it possible to run drush cron over a single module, something similar to "drush cron my_module"?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can do

```
drush php-eval 'my_module_cron();'
```

and it should run.

Comment: What is `my_module_cron();` in this context?

Comment: @Randell If would be the custom hook_cron() that you have defined in my_module.

Comment: Thanks @MPD! Can I replace it with 'some_nonhook_function()' if I'm using Elysia cron?

Comment: @Randell You can use php-eval to call / execute anything.  I do it all the time to test things.

Comment: Note though that whatever function you call may not have the proper variables in scope if it's not a cron function. I think hook_cron() implementations, on the other hand, should be self-contained.

Answer (score 0):

If you install the contrib project Ultimate Cron, you get extra Drush commands including:

```
drush cron:run my_module
```

which allows you to run a cron for a specific module.

Answer (score -1):

You can implement your own drush commands. Have look at the sandwich example code in the drush source package.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can just use,

```
drush cron module_name
```

Comment: Can you confirm which version of drush this works in?  I just looked at core.drush.inc in the version from PEAR, and I am not seeing arguments for that command.

Comment: My version reads 5.1

Comment: It doesn't work with an argument `module_name`.